# Create the cXML punch-out API in the Determine P2P application django project

Tags: python, django, xml, cxml-commercexml

I created an e-commerce site with django. I would like to integrate a cXML punchout to link the ecommerce site and the systems of my buyers,
I would like to know here how to configure the cXML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.028/cXML.dtd">
<cXML payloadID="?" timestamp="?" xml:lang="en-US">
<Header>
 <From>
   <Credential domain="?">
    <Identity>?</Identity>
  </Credential>
 </From>
 <To>
   <Credential domain="?">
     <Identity>?</Identity>
  </Credential>
 </To>
 <Sender>
   <Credential domain="?">
     <Identity>?</Identity>
     <CredentialMac type="FromSenderCredentials" algorithm="HMAC-SHA1-96" creationDate="?" 
  expirationDate="?">?</CredentialMac>
   </Credential>
   <UserAgent>Test</UserAgent>
 </Sender>
</Header>
<Request deploymentMode="test">
<PunchOutSetupRequest operation="create">
  <BuyerCookie>1234ABCD</BuyerCookie>
  <Extrinsic name="User">which user</Extrinsic>
  <BrowserFormPost><URL>https://example.com/?BrowserFormPost</URL></BrowserFormPost>
  <Contact>
    <Name xml:lang="en-US">myname</Name>
    <Email>whichmail@email</Email>
  </Contact>
  <SupplierSetup><URL>https://example.com/?SupplierSetup</URL></SupplierSetup>
</PunchOutSetupRequest>
```

For other information how to inform them ???
to adapt it to my project

Answer (score 0):

You can find the cXML user guide in the link below, if you want to set up your own service.
https://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLUsersGuide.pdf

Alternatively you can employ an existing punchout service like Tradecentric (~$300 a month), Greenwing (~$160 a month) or InstaPunchout (~$30 a month).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your reply.
Let me explain, a client of a company (which uses the Determine software) connects to my online sales site to place an order. Before validating his order, my online sales site must retrieve an order code from the customer's company system after validating
Is it possible ??
Do I also have to install punchout software to exchange with the client's system??

Comment: @PathiaNanto Yes, that's possible, InstaPunchout is a SaaS and you would need to install a plugin in your ecommerce system. But I think first you need to confirm with your buyer that they want to use punchout, and whether they want to use cXML or OCI.

Comment: With the buyer we agreed we will use cXML, now that they are the data I have to provide to the buyer and the data that I have to obtain on the buyer to make the link ???
For example the cXML document I posted on post